# Can't read icons on Mac dark mode lyx

Tags: lyx

Recently switched to mac and I found out that I canno't read the icons when in dark mode.
[image]

Please advise

Comment: the lyx bugtracker is here https://www.lyx.org/trac/wiki/BugTrackerHome

Answer (score 1):

This will be improved with LyX 2.4, as mentioned in the ["What is new in LyX 2.4?"](https://wiki.lyx.org/LyX/NewInLyX24#darkmode). You can also read the personal experience of a user who is testing the development version of 2.4 and what they say specifically about dark themes on Ricardo Berlasso's recent article this month ([in English](https://frommindtotype.wordpress.com/2022/09/05/lyx-progress-report/)) ([in Spanish](https://elpinguinotolkiano.wordpress.com/2022/09/05/lyx-reporte-de-progreso/)).

Unfortunately, there is no release date yet set for 2.4. If you are very motivated you could write to [lyx-devel](https://www.lyx.org/MailingLists#toc3) and ask to test the most recent development version, but I do not recommend it unless you are prepared to face bugs and you are not working with a coauthor who is using 2.3 (because LyX's major versions have different file formats).